# Converting column into rows

Tags: excel

I have a column of dates and numbers like this:

```
24/01/2016
1
0.123
24/01/2016
2
0.121
24/01/2016
3
0.104
24/01/2016
4
0.116
24/01/2016
5
0.091
...
```

How can I transform this column in excel so it appears in **three** columns as such:

```
24/01/2016 1 0.123
24/01/2016 2 0.121
24/01/2016 3 0.104
24/01/2016 4 0.116
24/01/2016 5 0.091
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/359617/convert-one-column-into-multiple-rows).

In short, one of the answers is to use the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS((ROW($A1)-1)*3+COLUMN(A1),1))
```